# SMTP ERROR: DATA END command failed: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, exchange-server-2010

I have strange error, when I am trying send email using

https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews

with just my msexchange username, password, it send email properly

but if I try to send message using phpmailer with my default **from email** I get following error

SMTP ERROR: DATA END command failed: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

What can be the possible reasons and How can I fix it

Comment: Is your from address different from your username?

Comment: yes, username is like manish and email address is manish@example.com